# Extarct particulr part of json string using python regex

Tags: json, regex, python-2.7

I have below json string:

```
"{"sweep_enabled":true,"product":"XYZ","page":"XYZ Profile","list":" {\"id\":205782,\"name\":\"Robert Shriwas\",\"gender\":\"F\",\"practicing_since\":null,\"years\":21,\"specializations\":[\"Mentor\"]}","form":{"q":"","city":"Delhi","locality":null},"cerebro":true}"
```

I want to extract list part out of above string:

```
{\"id\":205782,\"name\":\"Robert Shriwas\",\"gender\":\"F\",\"practicing_since\":null,\"years\":21,\"specializations\":[\"Mentor\"]}
```

How can I do this using python regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your JSON, it encloses another json object in the double quotes and is causing `json.loads` to fail. Try doing some transformation on json string before passing to `json.loads`.

As following works perfectly.

```
>>> p = json.loads('''{"sweep_enabled":true,"product":"XYZ","page":"XYZ Profile","list":{\"id\":205782,\"name\":\"Robert Shriwas\",\"gender\":\"F\",\"practicing_since\":null,\"years\":21,\"specializations\":[\"Mentor\"]},"form":{"q":"","city":"Delhi","locality":null},"cerebro":true}''')
```

And you extract the requited part as

```
>>> p["list"]
{u'name': u'Robert Shriwas', u'gender': u'F', u'specializations': [u'Mentor'], u'id': 205782, u'years': 21, u'practicing_since': None}
```

Check this out I could manage to correct the json you provided.

```
>>> p = '''{"sweep_enabled":true,"product":"XYZ","page":"XYZ Profile","list":" {\"id\":205782,\"name\":\"Robert Shriwas\",\"gender\":\"F\",\"practicing_since\":null,\"years\":21,\"specializations\":[\"Mentor\"]}","form":{"q":"","city":"Delhi","locality":null},"cerebro":true}'''
>>> q = re.sub(r'(:)\s*"\s*(\{[^\}]+\})\s*"',r'\1\2', p[1:-1])
>>> q
'"sweep_enabled":true,"product":"XYZ","page":"XYZ Profile","list":{"id":205782,"name":"Robert Shriwas","gender":"F","practicing_since":null,"years":21,"specializations":["Mentor"]},"form":{"q":"","city":"Delhi","locality":null},"cerebro":true'
>>> r = p[0] + q + p[-1]
>>> r
'{"sweep_enabled":true,"product":"XYZ","page":"XYZ Profile","list":{"id":205782,"name":"Robert Shriwas","gender":"F","practicing_since":null,"years":21,"specializations":["Mentor"]},"form":{"q":"","city":"Delhi","locality":null},"cerebro":true}'
>>> json.loads(r)
{u'product': u'XYZ', u'form': {u'q': u'', u'city': u'Delhi', u'locality': None}, u'sweep_enabled': True, u'list': {u'name': u'Robert Shriwas', u'gender': u'F', u'specializations': [u'Mentor'], u'id': 205782, u'years': 21, u'practicing_since': None}, u'cerebro': True, u'page': u'XYZ Profile'}
>>> s = json.loads(r)
>>> s['list']
{u'name': u'Robert Shriwas', u'gender': u'F', u'specializations': [u'Mentor'], u'id': 205782, u'years': 21, u'practicing_since': None}
>>>
```